# Create a Table depending of two variables

Tags: list-manipulation

I tried to create a table depending of two variables as:

```
W= Table[{G[[i]], G[[j]]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

I wanted it to look like 
$W=\{\{G[[1]],G[[1]]\},\{G[[1]],G[[2]]\},\{G[[1]],G[[3]]\},...,\{G[[3]],G[[3]]\}\}$,

but it does something like:

$W=\{\{\{G[[1]],G[[1]]\},\{G[[1]],G[[2]]\},\{G[[1]],G[[3]]\}\},...,\{G[[3]],G[[3]]\}\}\}$

It means, it groups the pairs in sets of three. What should I do?

Comment: Try `Flatten` and use the second argument,

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: ^^ Ok. I'm a beginner in mathematica but if I can help, then I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some different ways you could do this. I specify a `G` just to suppress errors.

```
G = {"a", "b", "c"}
tab = Table[{G[[i]], G[[j]]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
Flatten[tab, 1]
Join @@ tab
Map[Part[G, #] &, Join @@ Outer[List, Range[3], Range[3]], {2}]
Map[G[[#]] &, Tuples[Range[3], 2], {2}]
```

All yield:

```
{{"a", "a"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}, {"b", "a"}, {"b", "b"}, {"b", 
  "c"}, {"c", "a"}, {"c", "b"}, {"c", "c"}}
```

Note you could also get these parts using `Tuples`:

```
Tuples[G, 2]
```